# Getting error of - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter' with ExcelWriter

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a csv file this way

```
import pandas as pd
ns = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

removing Unknown row values

```
ns = (ns[ns['accountname']!='Unknown'])
```

reading another file

```
sfdc = pd.read_csv('SFDC.csv',engine='python')
```

Creating a new excel file using ExcelWriter

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx')
```

performing a merge

```
lookup = pd.merge(ns,sfdc[['Account ID','Account Status']],on=['Account ID'],how='left')
```

output to excel sheet

```
lookup.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='latest_sg',index=False)
```

getting an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

This was working earlier but strangely getting this error now.
Please help!

Comment: Try `pip install openpyxl`, then re-run your code

Comment: Done, But I get 'Requirement already satisfied'

Comment: Do you use any kind of virtual envrionment?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in /Users/Username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.0.0)
This is what I get

Comment: I tried in terminal to execute the .py file and it successfully runs but gives the error when in try to run under terminal in VS code

Comment: Open, VS code and click `ctrl` + `shift` + `p` and then choose `python: select interpreter` and tell me which one is highlightened.

Comment: Its Python 2.7.16 64 bit

Comment: That's why... now choose `~/anaconda3/bin/python3` and everything should work like a charm

Comment: I have 
python 3.6.10 64-bit('tensor': conda
~/opt/anaconda3/evs/tensor/bin/pyhton

Python 3.7.4 64 bit ('base': conda)
~/opt/anaconda3/bin/python

Python 3.7.6 64-bit ('ML': conda)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ML/bin/python

Python 3.8.1 64-bit
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

Python 3.8.1 64-bit
/usr/local/bin/python3

Which ont to select?

Comment: Open the terminal and run `which python3`... choose the output of this command

Comment: Did it help to resolve your issue??

Comment: Hi, yes it really helps. Thank you for the help! appreciate it

Comment: Glad I could help!! I've added the answer in order to help other people with the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was regarding the python version that Microsoft VS Code was pointing at. The best way to fix that is to:

- Detect the default python on your machine using `which python3` command
- Then, set the python interpreter on VS code to match the result of the former command. This can be done by clicking `ctrl` + `shift` + `p`. Then, choosing `python: select interpreter`. And highlight the python interpreter matching the former command.

Answer (score 1):

I had also faced a similar issue in pycharm, there was no import error when I imported the module same in my cmd terminal.

The issue lies here with the interpreter that you have selected for your project in your IDE. Change the interpreter to point to your virtual env python.exe